# How to handle Firebase Storage StorageException

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

My app gets images from Firebase storage. In the event that there exist no image I want to be able to handle the error. But I can't seem to get it working.

I have tried surrounding with try catch.

I have tried this

```
Future<dynamic> getImage(int index){
      return FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(widget.snap[index].data['英文品名']+".jpg").getDownloadURL().catchError((onError){
        print(onError);
      }); 
 }
```

and this

```
 Future<dynamic> getImage(int index){
   var imageStream;
   try {
       imageStream = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(widget.snap[index].data['英文品名']+".jpg").getDownloadURL();    
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
   }
   return imageStream;
 }
```

but I always get unhandled exception error and my app crashes.

```
E/StorageException(11819): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(11819): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(11819):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(11819): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(11819): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(11819):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(11819): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11819): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
```

How to handle this exception?
[Image of exception in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWreE.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're already catching the error, so what are you looking to add there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the problem is that even though I did add the catch the exception is still not being caught. It is as if i never added the catch to begin with.  I have added an image of the exception in vscode

Comment: I looked around in the code of the library, but I've been unable to find how to do that either. I'm going to ask around a bit.

Comment: Hi could you try using await instead so that you can be sure the "getDownloadUrl" is actually completing in your try catch? Something like "String url = await ref.getDownloadUrl();" That way you are sure that the error is happening within your try catch and should be caught. Maybe that will make things clearer.

Comment: Note also that you will see the StorageException output in your console even if the error is caught on the Dart side. So the stack trace snippet in your question is expected. The error in the image you shared is "I think" VSCode catching the error returned by the Storage Plugin. Try printing something else in the error handler, maybe it is getting caught after all.

Comment: @ArthurThompson I tried using the method you mentioned - String url = await ref.getDownloadUrl()- and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading the File will take different time based on the size of the Image. So most probably your error is because of the wrong combination of async and await. This code works for me.

```
Future<String> uploadSingleImage(File file) async {
    //Set File Name
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
        AuthRepository.getUser().uid +
        '.jpg';
    
    //Create Reference
    Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('Single Post Images')
        .child(fileName);

    //Now We have to check status of UploadTask
    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
    
    String url;
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      url = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });
    print('before return');
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you are trying to access the download url at a time where it hasn't been created yet.

You can wrap your upload code in an if statement like the example below. This way you guarantee that the upload task has completed successfully.

```
 if(storageRef
        .child(folderName)
        .putFile(fileName).isSuccessful)
      {
        url = await storage.child("folderName").child(fileName).getDownloadURL();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an Object exists or not like this:

```
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;

    final islandRef=FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child(widget.snap[index].data['英文品名']+".jpg");
            try {
        // returns Future<String> getDownloadURL()
              final var url= await islandRef.getDownloadURL();
              .getDownloadURL()
            } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch(error) {
              // if the Object does not exists
              if (error.code == 'object-not-found')) {
                  //DO something
              }
            
            }
```